# http://0.0.0.0:4567 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. with Backbone & Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, http-headers

I am using backbone trying to fetch data from firebase, and I am getting this error.

I believe I need to set the header somewhere so that it accepts cross origin requests but I'm not sure how I go about doing so?

```
  var ItemList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.item_list',
    render: function() {
      var that = this;
      var user = new Items();
      user.fetch({
        success: function() {
          that.$el.html('Hello');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: where are you fetching your data from?

Comment: typically those headers are set on the server, not the client.

Comment: I'm fetching my data from firebase, which should allow cross domain request

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out the solution was as simple as adding ".json" to the url

For example:

`https://podfuse.firebaseio.com/posts/mypost.json`

or

`https://podfuse.firebaseio.com/posts.json`

Hope that helps anyone else with this issue